# rails model different post types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I want to model different post types

`ImagePost` `VideoPost` `TextPost`. They all have different contents

I was going to go with post has_many polymorphic but rails doesn't support it

A previous stackoverflow post pointed me towards has_many_polymorphs gem but is deprecated

I need to be able to post different posts types and retrieve them in an instance show them on a feed
e.g.

```
@posts.each do .. 
  if type == video ... 
  elseif type == image ....
```

I'm new to rails so thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single table inheritance of Post model

```
 class class Post  < ActiveRecord::Base
  .....
 end
```

Than inherit this Post model into these model.

```
class VideoPost < Post

end

class ImagePost < Post
end
```

At migration you need to create a type column for different type of post. For details look at this [blog post](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the following

```
class Post  < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Create the an association table and add additional info on the association table, description, etc etc.
    has_many :images, through: image_posts
    has_many :image_posts
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Image specific
end
```

Doing this, @post.image_posts.count > 0 indicates there are multiple image_posts.

Or you could also achieve the goal by polymorphic relation:

```
class VideoPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
end

class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, as: :postable
end
```

In this case @feed.posts.each will check the postable_type, which is the model type instead.

Comment: when a post could be an image, video or text how would I check what type it is?

Comment: Updated the answer. type is defined by the model. Use a count check should solve ur problem.

Comment: One do not have have to add feed model. As mentioned in the question. You would like to have a list of posts for one feed, thus the Feed model is added for illustration purpose.

Comment: I would prefer to go with the solution of separate model for Video and Image. Since typically these asset elements can be included by other models. for example class User could have images for profile photo. class Comment might have image / video too.

Answer (score 0):

STI is the way to go. I guess columns of all three type should be same or similar at least. So Single tale inheritance would be the best choice.